# umap failed to cluster the cells

Tags: scrnaseq, single-cell, umap

I tried umap visualization with [`scanpy`](https://github.com/scverse/scanpy) :

```
sc.pp.normalize_total(adata, target_sum=1e6)
sc.pp.log1p(adata, base=2)
sc.pp.highly_variable_genes(adata, flavor='cell_ranger', n_top_genes=400)

sc.pp.scale(adata, zero_center=True, max_value=None, copy=False, layer=None, obsm=None)
sc.pp.pca(adata, n_comps=50, use_highly_variable=True, svd_solver='arpack')
sc.pp.neighbors(adata, n_neighbors=50)

sc.tl.umap(adata, min_dist=0.5, spread=1.0)
sc.pl.umap(adata, color='fullname', use_raw=False, save='samples_umap.pdf')
```

version

```
anndata     0.7.5
scanpy      1.6.1
```

But the cells can't separate well
[image]

I tried another small dataset with `scanpy` using the same parameters as before:
[image: 1]

`sc.tl.umap` still failed to down dimension the data properly.

Then I tried the original [`umap` package](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting.html) using the same data set:

```
import umap
import umap.plot
mapper = umap.UMAP().fit(adata.X)
umap.plot.points(mapper)
```

Now the original `umap` package can do down dimension very well:
[image: 2]

I think there may be something wrong with the `umap` function in `scanpy`
Can anyone please let me know the reason?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more code and data, this can't be debugged. But first question would be does the data pass basic QC (e.g. look at cellranger web summaries or equivalent). If yes, you could trying different normalisation (code not shown) and/or no scaling. Try `sc.tl.umap()` with default params. Plot the PCA, try t-SNE. Plot the basic QC metrics following the introductory scanpy tutorial. That is how I would start debugging

Comment: I compare the `umap` in `scanpy` with the original [`umap`](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting.html) (https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting.html)  using the same dataset, the original `umap` works well, I think the problem is in `scanpy`. I edited my question to include this.
Do you have some suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: @DanLi It might be this: https://github.com/scverse/scanpy/issues/2045 or related. Try with the latest scanpy version and consider reporting to scanpy github if not already reported

Comment: Yes, thanks. @Chris_Rands